# How to highlight rows if they contain duplicate data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following data:

```
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| id   |            number |             colour |
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
| 1766 |                53 | red                |
| 1767 |                 3 | green              |
| 1768 |               202 | green              |
| 1769 |                52 | blue               |
| 1770 |                56 | orange             |
| 1771 |                90 | yellow             |
| 1772 |                28 | teal               |
| 1773 |               276 | purple             |
| 1774 |                23 | black              |
| 1775 |                23 | orange             |
+------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

The important column here in the `colour` column. I want to display all the above rows (in an HTML table) but I want to highlight any rows which have duplicate colours. i.e. the two green rows and the two orange rows.

Ideally I would end up with an extra column that would contain a boolean (or anything really) that I could check when displaying the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you **don't need** any subqueries or anything if you don't have much data.

Just hash each row (or part of the row you need to check) as you display them like this:

```
$hashes = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rowHash = md5(implode("", $row), true);
    $isDuplicate = isset($hashes[$rowHash]));
    <... printing row contents ...>
    $hashes[$rowHash] = true;
}
```

This solution will work until you have too much rows for display on a page. Then you may also cache hash value in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html):

```
SELECT `id`, `number`, `colour` FROM `table`
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) > 1 `duplicate` FROM `table` GROUP BY `colour`) `tmp` USING (`colour`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but you could just count the number of times you see the current color:

```
SELECT id, number, colour,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE colour = t.colour) AS repeats
FROM table t
```

Ofcourse, you only want to know if there is 1 other, so you could go with just finding 1 other row.

```
SELECT id, number, colour,
  (SELECT id FROM table WHERE colour = t.colour AND id!=t.id LIMIT 1) AS repeats
FROM table t
```

I'm not completely sure what happens if there is no second row, so you might need to account for NULL values there, but I presume you get the general idea ;)

Comment: How expensive is doing an sub query like this?

Comment: The second one isn't really expensive, though you are doing it for each row. Check out the `EXPLAIN` (just prepend the word to you query) output to see what is happening. It really depends on the size of things if you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
select table.id, table.number, table.colour, t.count 
from table 
join (select colour, count(colour) as c from table group by colour) as t 
on table.colour=t.colour
```

would yield:

```
+------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| id   |            number |             colour |     count |
+------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+
| 1766 |                53 | red                |         1 |
| 1767 |                 3 | green              |         2 |
| 1768 |               202 | green              |         2 |
| 1769 |                52 | blue               |         1 |
| 1770 |                56 | orange             |         2 |
| 1771 |                90 | yellow             |         1 |
| 1772 |                28 | teal               |         1 |
| 1773 |               276 | purple             |         1 |
| 1774 |                23 | black              |         1 |
| 1775 |                23 | orange             |         2 |
+------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```