# PHP Highlight Table Rows Of Duplicate Values From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched high and low for an answer or even tutorial on how to do this.

I have a table which contains some data. 
The data is displayed in an HTML table.

What I want to do is highlight rows that have duplicate values.

Below is the actual data in my table. Some of these contain duplicates.

```
Alpha Tag   Frequency   Country Usage   Programmed
WILD 3  151.50500   USA No
WILD 2  151.51500   USA No
PKALT1  151.57000   USA No
QAP 151.59500   USA No
LKJ 2   151.68500   USA No
WILD 4  151.74000   USA No
SUMMIT  151.77500   USA No
ALYE 6  151.80500   USA No
PKALT2  151.82000   USA No
MURS 151.82 151.82000   USA No
ALYE 5  151.83500   USA No
PNALT1  151.88000   USA No
MURS 151.88 151.88000   USA No
H ROAD  151.92500   USA No
PNALT2  151.94000   USA No
MURS 151.94 151.94000   USA No
MBCON2  151.95500   USA No
ALYE 4  152.30000   USA No
WBI K   152.91500   USA No
MBCON1  152.93000   USA No
WILD 1  152.99000   USA No
ALCHWY  153.03500   USA No
ALYE 7  153.05000   USA No
WBI A2  153.15500   USA No
AMB 2   154.05000   USA No
LADD 1  154.10000   CA  No
AK RL2  154.31500   USA No
LADD 3  154.32500   CA  No
AMB 1   154.38500   USA No
WLD EQ  154.54000   USA No
MURS 154.57 - Blue Dot  154.57000   USA No
MURS 154.60 - Green Dot 154.60000   USA No
B SHIT  154.60000   USA No
KPD 154.72500   USA No
FPD 155.01000   USA No
AROW 1  155.19000   USA No
WPD 155.37000   USA No
MOA 155.82000   USA No
DOT 2   156.12000   USA No
ALYE 1  157.43000   USA No
LKJ 1   157.66500   USA No
ALYE 2  158.28000   USA No
ALYE 3  158.33500   USA No
LADD 2  158.94000   CA  No
DOT 1   159.13000   USA No
LTIHNS  159.63000   USA No
LTIFBX  159.84000   USA No
AK WST  159.90000   USA No
LTIPBY  159.96000   USA No
C CAKE  160.08000   USA No
SLEP 1  160.09500   USA No
WBI A1  160.20000   USA No
AROW 2  162.27000   USA No
AK RL1  164.62500   USA No
SLEP 2  170.50000   USA No
LADD 4  173.37000   CA  No
```

My PHP function for reading MySQL is:

```
function getFrequencies() {
$conn = getConnected("websiteData");
$frequencyQuery = "SELECT * FROM frequencies ORDER BY Frequency";

$frequencyResult = mysqli_query($conn, $frequencyQuery);

while ($frequencyRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($frequencyResult))
{ 
   echo "<tr>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Name'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Frequency'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Country'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Programmed'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
}
}
```

I know that this is not a site to get code built on without trying something yourself, but the truth is I don't know where to start. I'm not asking for someone to do this for me 100% but I am seeking guidance.

I have seen plenty of answers on using MySQL `JOIN` but I do not wish to do this. I just simply want to highlight those specific rows so that I can go in and change the records or delete them.

I did find this Q&A but it gave me a headache because I don't understand how the accepted answer comes into play: [How to highlight rows if they contain duplicate data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840463/how-to-highlight-rows-if-they-contain-duplicate-data)

Also there are only two columns I wish to check for duplicates. The `Alpha Tag` column and the `Frequency` column.

Now that an answer has pointed me in the right direction, this is what I have attempted so far with no luck, but it's a start:

```
function getFrequencies() {
$conn = getConnected("websiteData");
 //$frequencyQuery = "SELECT Name, Frequency, Country, Programmed, count(*) FROM frequencies GROUP BY Frequency ORDER BY Name";
 $frequencyQuery = "SELECT Name, Frequency, Country, Programmed, count(*) FROM frequencies GROUP BY Frequency ORDER BY Name";
$frequencyResult = mysqli_query($conn, $frequencyQuery);

while ($frequencyRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($frequencyResult))
{ 
   if ($frequencyRow['count'] > 1) { echo '<tr class="danger">' . PHP_EOL; } else { echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL; }
    echo "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Name'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Frequency'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Country'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "<td>" . $frequencyRow['Programmed'] . "</td>" . PHP_EOL . 
    "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
}
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should just group your data? `SELECT <fields>, count(*) FROM frequencies GROUP BY <fields> ORDER BY Frequency` You can't do a select * when you group by. Anything you select, must be part of your group by condition unless it's an aggregate function such as count, avg, sum, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT Name, Frequency, Country, Programmed, count(*) as count
FROM frequencies
GROUP BY Frequency;
```

Then in your PHP `while` you can highlight duplicates with:

```
if ($frequencyRow['count'] > 1) {
    // there are duplicates
    // apply special css
} else {
    // one row only
}
```

**Update:**

Another way to write the query to show and keep duplicates (no grouping):

```
SELECT f.Name, f.Frequency, f.Country, f.Programmed, 
   (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM frequencies
    WHERE Frequency = f.Frequency
   ) as count
FROM frequencies f
;
```

Comment: I've tried some of what you suggested(your query here doesn't match up to my MySQL table) and I didn't get a highlight, but I did edit my question to include what I just attempted at the bottom.

Comment: in your query you need to replace `count(*)` with `count(*) as count` as shown in my code sample.

Comment: Whoops overlooked that. Ok the rows are highlighting now which is a plus, but the duplicate results aren't showing for some reason. It says I have duplicates but only one shows up instead of a pair.

Comment: Example:

MURS 151.94 151.94000
PNALT2 151.94000

These two have duplicate frequencies, but when I use your query only one shows up when checking for duplicates.

Comment: My initial queries group rows which will de-duplicate duplicates. I have updated my answer with another way to write the queries to show and keep duplicates.